# What is the point of using titleTextStyle?

Tags: android, android-theme, android-styles

What is the point of using titleTextStyle?  If you have a theme and you define the actionbar, isn't the text style, and color already being applied to the action bar?  What is the benefit of defining titleTextStyle attributes?  The two codes below seem to yield the same result.  Whats the reason to use one over the other?   The only thing I could think of is the text background perhaps?  you could have a background for the text and another for the actual actionbar?   But there must be more cause adding textBackground would be easier than defining a set of text attributes assuming thats the only difference, so I don't know what I'm missing.  All other posts just seemed to be issues with support library and how to define styles in general.  Thanks

```
<style name="WindowTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:typeface">serif</item>
    <!-- Action bar info -->
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBarTheme</item>
    <item name="actionButtonStyle">@style/ActionBarButtonStyle</item>
    <item name="actionMenuTextAppearance"> @style/ActionBarListings </item>
</style>
<!-- Action bar definitions -->
<style name="ActionBarTheme" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    **<item name="android:typeface">serif</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#ff0014ff</item>**
    <item name="android:background">#ffff0000</item>
</style>
<style name="ActionBarButtonStyle" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">#ff0014ff</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>
<style name="ActionBarListings" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">#ff0014ff</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>




<style name="WindowTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:typeface">serif</item>
    <!-- Action bar info -->
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBarTheme</item>
    <item name="actionButtonStyle">@style/ActionBarButtonStyle</item>
    <item name="actionMenuTextAppearance"> @style/ActionBarListings </item>
</style>
<!-- Action bar definitions -->
<style name="ActionBarTheme" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:typeface">serif</item>
    **<item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/titleTextStyleAttributes</item>**
    <item name="android:background">#ffff0000</item>
</style>
**<style name="titleTextStyleAttributes" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">#ff0014ff</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>**
<style name="ActionBarButtonStyle" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">#ff0014ff</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>
<style name="ActionBarListings" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">#ff0014ff</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>
```